# TypeORM (MySQL) connection lost event handling

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

When using TypeORM with MySQL, how do I properly handle situations like db server dies for some reason? I connect to db using **createConnection** method and able to catch only errors that may occur while initial establishing this connection. How to catch any further errors in a proper way? For now I just ping my database with "select 1" query every second and don't think that it's a clever approach.